# String literal using as reference

Tags: java, string, literals

`string s2="abc"` 
Because a string object is created for every string literal you can use a string literal any place you can use a string object. For example you can call methods directly on a quoted string as if it were an object reference.
`System.out.println("abc".length());`

I saw this in Herbert schildt. Can anyone explain me how string literal can be used as reference.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: What does "be used as a reference" mean?

Comment: The example (`"abc".length()`) shows it being used as a reference. Could you clarify what aspect is confusing for you at the moment?

Comment: `"abc"` is compiled in a .class as a UTF-8 byte sequence. The ClassLoader turns that in a `String` stored in "the constant pool." Maybe comparable with `new int[] {1, 2}.length`.

Answer (score 0):

String literals is an indirect way to create `String` object, and it returns a reference to that object.

Therefore you can use this as any other object reference: assign to variables, pass as parameters, compare to other references, or call methods.